# Convert Decimal Number to Binary without using Array

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, decimal

I want to make a java code that converts any decimal number inputted, into binary number. Although the array method is easy, it doesn't actually prints a number(it prints array), nor does it seem to correctly use the algorithm we use manually. So I'm trying to do it without array. The problem is it sometimes giving correct answers, and sometimes giving wrong answers. I think the problem might be in multiplying by zero in the last cycle of loop, but I'm not sure. The code I wrote as comment was a failed try to resolve the issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecToBin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long dec = 0, num = 0, rem = 0;
        
        System.out.print("Enter A Decimal Number: ");
        dec = sc.nextLong();
        while(dec > 0){
            rem = dec % 2;
            num += rem;
            num *= 10;
            dec /= 2;

        }
        // if(num % 100 == 10){
        //     num = num/10;
        // }
        System.out.println("Binary Equivalent: " + num);


    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, all numbers in a computer are binary.  There are no decimal numbers.  You typically want to *print* a number in binary when you do this.

Comment: Can you give an example of a wrong answer this code gives?  It's harder for us to test it if we don't already know where the problems are.

Comment: @markspace I wanted to say that using array only outputs an array. But I want to get a variable as output, in my case 'num'.

Comment: @markspace for example, if you input 6, it gives 110 which is right. But if you input 5, it gives 1010, which should be 101

Comment: The approach of representing the result as a decimal number with only `1`s and `0`s is a very bad idea.  The input range is extremely limited (1023 for `int` and `524288` for `long`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found following "direct" issues with your code:

1. You are not reversing the final number. In the manual way of converting DEC->BIN, we reverse the final representation. Hint: Dry run for input 11
2. You are doing `num += rem; num *= 10`. The order is wrong. You should be multiplying it before you add the remainder. eg. Your code will output `1010` for `5`, instead of `101`.
3. By your method, you are trying to represent decimal number into its binary representation as `int`, which limits your input to `2047`, as `2048` and above need 11+ digits for their binary representation and you can't have that in `int`. You should use `String` if you don't want to use array. Also, reversing would be easier.

something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecToBin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dec = 0, num = 0;
        
        System.out.print("Enter A Decimal Number: ");
        dec = sc.nextInt();
        String bi = "";
        while(dec > 0){
            int rem = dec % 2;
            // num *= 10;
            // num += rem;
            bi += Character.toString(rem + 48);
            dec /= 2;

        }
        // if(num % 100 == 10){
        //     num = num/10;
        // }
        System.out.println("Binary Equivalent: " + new StringBuilder(bi).reverse().toString());


    }
}
```

Comment: Well now that you pointed it out, I feel stupid that I overlooked the 'reverse' part. Thank you very much, you're a great help. And in reply your third point, I am using 'long' instead of 'int'.

Comment: Using long would help you for another 10 binary digits, so, instead of 2047, your input limit will be (2^21-1). If that's enough for your use case, good for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time answering, so please let me know if anything is off :-)

You could try to use a String as intermediate. Short and simple.... But i dont know if that counts as an Array :-)
Your while-part would be something like this:

```
    String strBin = "";
    while(dec > 0){
        strBin = String.valueOf(dec%2) + strBin;
        dec /= 2;
    }
    num = Long.valueOf(strBin);
```

The order of bits in the binairy number is correct by adding in front of the previous String, so building up the result from right to left.
Also, i would not use a Long (last line... num), because it limits your max result.  But if you must.....  meh

Answer (score -1):

This problem lends its self to a recursive solution

```java
  private static int DecToBin(final int input, final int result) {
    if (input == 0) {
      return result;
    }
    return DecToBin(input / 2, result * 10 + input % 2);
  }
```

Comment: Fails for any input number > 1023, and if you returned `long` it would fail for input > 524287.